# What is the wrong with this dojo code?

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is just a piece of test dojo code I am writing. I am a beginner to Dojo and I can't understand what is wrong with this. The alert button is not displayed on load. Furthermore,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>

<!-- load Dojo -->

</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-    config="async:true, parseOnLoad:true">
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);
require(["dojo/ready"],function(ready){
alert("BLAH");
});
</script>

<div id="targetID">
Hello world
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't put javascript in the same tag where you have src= and close your script tags

Comment: I tried doing something on the lines of a scipt tag pair with the source only  followed by a separate set of script tags  where I wrote the code itself.But that gives me an undefined reference error regarding dojo itself. Also I have closed my script tags.

Comment: FYI - The script tag was closed, but not formatted properly to display on the stack overflow site, thus my edit of the question.

Comment: Anurag, you should post that code and give specific information on the undefined reference error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwAhY/ . Are u sure that `data-dojo-    config` in your page is without spaces?

Comment: Yeah,I'm sure it's without spaces.